# On connecting with socket using socket.io it's returning disconnected socket object intermittently

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io, etherpad, engine.io

I am using socket.io to establish a socket connection. The server i am trying to establish connection with is first behind a Amazon ELB then a HAProxy load balancer. I am using this code:

```
socket = io.connect(url, {
  'path': exports.baseURL + "socket.io",
  'resource': resource,
  'max reconnection attempts': 3,
  'sync disconnect on unload' : false,
  'transports' : ['websocket']
});
```

Almost **half of the times this call is returning the valid socket object** but **other times it's returning disconnected socket object** of this type:

```
Socket
  _callbacks:Object
  acks:Object
  connected:false
  disconnected:true
  ids:0
  io:Manager
  json:Socket
  nsp:"/"
  receiveBuffer:Array[0]
  sendBuffer:Array[0]
  subs:Array[3]
```

Main this here to notice is here *connected:false* and *disconnected:true* means the connection is not getting established. Can someone please help here?